# Как узнать пароль пользователя Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, есть база данных с 5-ю пользователями, от одного из них пароль известен но привилегии не все, как узнать пароли от остальных пользователей ? имею доступ к серверу где находиться сама БД. Потому как до меня с базой работал не один человек и пароль достался только от последнего с неполными правами. Всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 4):

Узнать пользователей и пароли вам может помочь запрос:

```
SELECT username, password FROM dba_users;
```

Но вот к огорчению хакеров пароли хранятся в виде хеша. Так что посмотреть их вы не сможете. Если у вас есть права администратора, то вы можете их сменить. Также их можно перенести в другую базу.

Comment: Как узнать есть права администратора или нет ?

Comment: И сразу следующий вопрос, если БД нужно обслуживать, а админ. прав нет, БД грубо говоря можно хоронить ? разве нет путей решения ? или расшифровки хэша ?

Comment: В таком случае служба безопасности обязана применить терморектальный криптоанализ к бывшему админу.

Comment: Хэш это такая штука, которая из пароля делает по специальному алгоритму код. Обратного алгоритма нет. Если вы вводите пароль, то алгоритмом генерируется хэш и сверяется с тем, что в базе. То есть вариант только перебор. Есть какие-то онлайн сервисы перебора. Ты вводишь хэш и поиском по базе может быть найден пароль, а может быть и не найден... Если пароль простой, то может найтись

Comment: Чтобы узнать какие есть права можно зайти с правами администратора (заколдованный круг) и выполнить запрос:
select * from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTEE = 'здесь_имя_пользователя';
Этот запрос выводит роли пользователя. На самом деле прав много и они раскиданы по нескольким таблицам, но ролей может быть достаточно

Comment: @Ethernets Пользователь операционной системы на сервере под которым был установлен оракл может стать админом без пароля, если не устанавливались дополнительные средства аутентификации. для этого надо использовать утилиту `svrmgrl` и первой командой писать `connect internal` или в более новых версиях, если такой утилиты нет, то использовать sqlplus коннектится под `sys as sysdba` без проля. После чего спокойно меняете все пароли какие захотите

Comment: @Mike А если sys  тоже запаролен как быть ?

Comment: @Ethernets Вы в этом убедились ? Он без пароля не входит если вы из под другого пользователя ОС идете, нежели тот, под которым стартует оракл. Если с пользователем угадали, то пустой пароль должен принять. На самом оракле рекомендуют примерно то же https://community.oracle.com/thread/899559?tstart=0

Comment: Mike хороший совет дает. Если по русски, то. Запускаешь cmd, вводишь команду: sqlplus /nolog и после нее следующую: connect / as sysdba
Если делать это под пользователем операционной системы под которым был установлен Oracle, то должен войти без пароля

Comment: @Mike Хорошо завтра на работе попробую, дома работает, если и на работе мне удастся подключиться как sys, как изменить пароль пользователя  ? и дать нужные права ?  Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets Я вот там чуть выше ссылочку давал. Там написано. `ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY new_password;` А права ... а зачем и что править в правах

Comment: @Mike Всем доброго времени суток, вообщем такая проблема на работе при выполнении команды **connect / as sysdba** получаю ошибку **ORA-01031**, почитав на просторах, проблема с разными паролями, как правильно изменить пароль sys не навредив работе БД и других пользователей ?

Comment: @Mike По поиску файла PWDSID.ORA ничего не найдено, в какую папочку нужно положить данный файл ?

Comment: @Ethernets попробуйте выполнить connect / as sysdba  под другим пользователем. Похоже, что этот пользователь системы не входит в группы ORA_DBA, ORA_OPER

Comment: @AlexejSommer жаль но увы к другим пользователям я доступа не имею, потому как ... человек который вел данный сервер 3 года как уволился и не паролей ничего не оставил .... сволочь, как теперь быть ?

Comment: @Ethernets Значит вам нужно использовать утилиту svrmgrl, которую вам Mike подсказал.

Comment: @AlexejSommer такой утилиты нет, её можно установить отдельно ?

Comment: Да, похоже она только до 8-ого оракла шла в комплекте. Попробуй на сервере найти файл sqlnet.ora и проверить нет ли в нем строки SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE). Эта строка может не пускать зайти без пароля с помощью connect / as sysdba

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38266/discussion-between-ethernets-and-alexej-sommer).